# how do I toggle table properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to modify webpage such as

1. not show table at first
2. after finishing certain event show table

so I made a variable for toggling a table. However problem is that it becomes hidden when the page is reloaded.

```
// when page is ready
var toggle = false;

if (toggle == true) { show table }
else                { hide table }

/// during finish action -> toggle = true;
```

code here
https://jsfiddle.net/r4jd0wo7/

```
// after this event, show table
$(document).on("click","#searchgroupsubmit",function() {
  $('#checkgroup').val($('.list-group-item.group.active').find("input[name='groupdeletecheck']").val());
      jQuery("#searchList").submit();
});

// I made a function for toogle table
function toggle_visibility() {
  var e = document.getElementById("table1");
  var f = document.getElementById("pagenation1");

  if (e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display == '')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = 'block';

  if (f.style.display == 'block' || f.style.display == '')
    f.style.display = 'none';
  else
    f.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: You will have to store the visibility outside the page somewhere and look it up.

Comment: @wazz like session or cookies? could you share some ideas?

Comment: Yes and yes. Local storage (browser), json file, database.